# Unable to solve dictionary update value error while parsing financial statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm parsing the below financial statement and trying to create dictionaries out of them. But I keep getting this error: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Below is the cleaned financial statement:

```
[[XXX XXX LTD.'],
 ['Statement of Loss and Retained Earnings'],
 ['For the Year Ended May', 'XX,', 'XXXX'],
 ['Unaudited - See Notice To Reader'],
 ['XXXX', 'XXXX'],
 ['REVENUE', 'XXX,XXX,XXX', 'XXX,XXX,XXX']
]
```

Below is the code that I'm using to create dictionaries:

## Python 3.6

```
    for temp in cleaned_list:
        if len(temp) == 1:
            statement[temp[0]] = temp[0]
        elif len(temp) > 1:
            statement[temp[0]] = {}
            for temp_1 in temp[1:]:
                statement[temp[0]].update(temp_1)
```

If the list has a length of one, I want to make the entry of that list both its dictionary key and value. If the list entry has multiple items, I want to make the first entry the key, and the remaining entries the values. I'm not sure what the error that I'm getting is, and why it's occurring. Why do you think this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use just `statement[temp[0]] = temp_1` instead of `statement[temp[0]].update(temp_1)`?  `temp_1` is not a dictionary, you can't use it as parameter for `update()`. As far as I understand, you are trying to update just 1 pair. `update()` can update more than one pairs but you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update), the `update()` method updates a dictionary with elements from a dictionary object or an iterable object of key/value pairs. You are getting an error message because you are trying to update your dictionary without specifying the key associated with the values in `temp_1`.

This should do the trick:

```
statement={}
for temp in cleaned_list:
    key=temp[0]
    statement.update({key:None})
    if len(temp)==1:
        value=key
        statement.update({key:value})
    elif len(temp) > 1:
        values=temp[1:]
        statement.update({key:values})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
statement = {}    
for temp in cleaned_list:
    if len(temp) == 1:
        statement[temp[0]] = temp[0]
    elif len(temp) > 1:
        if temp[0] in statement:
            statement[temp[0]].extend(temp[1:])
        else:
            statement[temp[0]] = temp[1:]
```

Explanation (update): The `statement.update()` replaces the value in the key and at the same time you are already re-setting the dictionary key pair with `statement[temp[0]] = {}`. So, it doesn't seem like you want to update the value but append the list items. I use `extend()` so that you don't have a value list with list items like `'key': ['foo', 'bar', ['foo2', 'bar2']]`, which instead will become `'key': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo2', 'bar2']` when using `extend()`. Also, I added the if statement to check if the key already exists.

Comment: Add some explanation please.